# How to consolidate a data frame in which the date variable is repeated in a column next to each variable

Tags: r

I inherited a csv file with data in the following form:

```
date        v1  date.1      v2  date.2      v3
2015-01-01  1   2015-01-01  4   2015-01-02  5
2015-01-02  2   2015-01-03  5   2015-01-03  2
2015-01-03  3   2015-01-04  3   2015-01-04  6
2015-01-04  4   2015-01-05  2   2015-01-05  2
2015-01-05  5   2015-01-06  6   2015-01-06  4
2015-01-06  6   2015-01-07  3   2015-01-07  5
2015-01-07  7   2015-01-08  1   2015-01-09  1
```

The actual file has more than 70 date-variable pairs

NB: The dates in columns 1, 3, and 5 are not identical

I would like to clean up this data in R so that I have one column with dates and then the values of v1, v2, and v3 corresponding to those dates in the next three columns:

```
date        v1  v2  v3
2015-01-01  1   4   NA
2015-01-02  2   NA  5
2015-01-03  3   5   2
2015-01-04  4   3   6
2015-01-05  5   2   2
2015-01-06  6   6   4
2015-01-07  7   3   5
2015-01-08  NA  1   NA
2015-01-09  NA  NA  1
```

If all the date (date, date.1, . . . date.n) columns were identical, I could simply remove them. Because they are not, however, removing them would incorrectly associate some variables with the wrong dates because of their position (e.g, var3 would appear to have a value of 5 for 2015-01-01 even though there was no value for var3 on that date).

I considered stack (followed by a eliminating non-unique values), but given the date-variable pairing of the original data set, this does not seem workable.

I considered using outer_join in the dplyr package, which would likely work if all the date columns had the same name (i.e., if each was called "date" rather than "date", "date.1", etc.). I could rename each date column, but given the large number of them, this would be cumbersome.

Finally, I considered merge, but this would seem to require first breaking the large data frame (including all the date-variable pairs) into multiple data frames. Moreover, again because of the different names of the date variables, I'd have to merge them one by one.

I suspect there may be a way to get where I am going with an apply command, but my skill with the apply commands is limited.

Thanks in advance for help and guidance.

Comment: Have you considered the `merge.zoo` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using the following for-loop?

```
res <- merge(df[,1:2], df[,3:4], by = c(1,1), all = TRUE)

for(i in seq_len((length(df)-4)/2)){
    res <- merge(res, df[,(3 + i*2):(4 + i*2)], by = c(1,1), all = TRUE)
}
res
        date v1 v2 v3
1 2015-01-01  1  4 NA
2 2015-01-02  2 NA  5
3 2015-01-03  3  5  2
4 2015-01-04  4  3  6
5 2015-01-05  5  2  2
6 2015-01-06  6  6  4
7 2015-01-07  7  3  5
8 2015-01-08 NA  1 NA
9 2015-01-09 NA NA  1
```

Comment: Thank you RStudent. This was  very helpful. I did run into a problem that I haven't solved yet. Namely, I had two NA rows at the end of my first pair. The loop replicated those across all pairs. Easy to manage, but would love to know why that happened.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it using the package `reshape2`. I'm sure there are more concise ways, but `reshape2` has really good tools for problems like this. The process is pretty easy to read, too.

```
# Split the paired columns and put them in a list 
# so you can work on all three at once
df_list <- list(df[1:2], df[3:4], df[5:6])



# Melt each chunk then stack them.
# If you're not familiar with "melting" and "casting" data
# and the reshape2 package, it's well worth learning.
library(reshape2)

df_melt <- ldply(df_list, .fun = function(x) {

    # Melt it
    x_melt <- melt(x,
                   id.var = names(x)[1],
                   measure.var = names(x)[2]
    )

    # Rename it
    names(x_melt) <- c("date", "variable", "value")


    # Return it
    x_melt

})


# Now you've got a stack of records where each value
# is defined by two other variables: the date and the
# variable of origin (v1, v2, v3).
# Cast that data wide
df_wide <- dcast(df_melt,
                 date ~ variable,
                 value.var = "value"
)
```

Comment: As I understand he wants to avoid having to make the chunks manually, as there are many (70) date-column pairs

Comment: I guess you can do something like this in order to create a list. `odd <- seq(1, 70, 2); lapply(odd, function(x) mydf[, c(x, x+1)])`. Then, you can avoid the manual work and apply this process.

Comment: Thank you, Matt Parker, RStudent, and jazzurro. Matt's suggestion was helpful, but as RStudent noted, I was trying to avoid creating naming each pair manually. I was able to build a list with the three three pairs using jazzurro's code, but then could not reshape it. I got the following error: Error in names(x_melt) <- c("date", "variable", "value") : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Comment: @DavidS Sorry for the oversight - that is definitely not something you'd want to do manually. jazzurro's snippet produces a list identical to my `df_list` using just the example data, so it's hard to know what the error might be in the full set. You might try applying that snippet to just `head(df)` - that *should* give you a list of 70 6-row data.frames, which is small enough you could manually review for odd ones.

Comment: @DavidS If you like, you could post the output of `dput(head(df))` for the full dataset - that might make it easier to identify the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From this example, it seems possible to transform your "data.frame" to long format:

```
lDF = data.frame(date = unlist(DF[grep("^date", names(DF))]),
                 var = rep(names(DF)[grep("v", names(DF))], each = nrow(DF)),
                 val = unlist(DF[grep("v", names(DF))]))
lDF
```

Therefrom, a convenient approach would be something like:

```
mat = array(NA, c(length(levels(lDF$date)), length(levels(lDF$var))), 
            list(levels(lDF$date), levels(lDF$var)))
mat[as.matrix(lDF[c("date", "var")])] = lDF$val              
mat
#           v1 v2 v3
#2015-01-01  1  4 NA
#2015-01-02  2 NA  5
#2015-01-03  3  5  2
#2015-01-04  4  3  6
#2015-01-05  5  2  2
#2015-01-06  6  6  4
#2015-01-07  7  3  5
#2015-01-08 NA  1 NA
#2015-01-09 NA NA  1
```

The result is "matrix", but it's easy to convert to the desired "data.frame" `cbind.data.frame(date = rownames(mat), mat)`.
"DF":

```
DF = structure(list(date = structure(1:7, .Label = c("2015-01-01", 
"2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-05", "2015-01-06", 
"2015-01-07"), class = "factor"), v1 = 1:7, date.1 = structure(1:7, .Label = c("2015-01-01", 
"2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-05", "2015-01-06", "2015-01-07", 
"2015-01-08"), class = "factor"), v2 = c(4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 
3L, 1L), date.2 = structure(1:7, .Label = c("2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", 
"2015-01-04", "2015-01-05", "2015-01-06", "2015-01-07", "2015-01-09"
), class = "factor"), v3 = c(5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L)), .Names = c("date", 
"v1", "date.1", "v2", "date.2", "v3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Now, that I paid closer attention to the answers, the concept above is, already, included along the lines of Matt Parker's approach, but with base tools.

Comment: Thanks, alexis_laz. This is very elegant right up to the conversion from a matrix to a dataframe that requires more manual work than I want to do with 70 date-variable pairs.